# Refreshing mongo credentials in Quarkus

Tags: mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm trying to use AWS Secrets Manager to store my Mongo DB credentials for the Quarkus application that uses Panache.
In order to do this, I implemented a custom CredentialsProvider (https://quarkus.io/guides/credentials-provider#custom-credentials-provider). However, I found that CredentialsProvider is called only during the first access to db because MongoClient is instantiated as a bean and is cached in arc ApplicationContext.
So my question: is there any way to refresh Mongodb credentials in runtime without restarting application?

Comment: I would suggest opening a new issue

Comment: created [the issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/38519)